# Symfony2 - Composer clear cache error

Tags: php, linux, symfony, composer-php

When trying to clear the cache on my symfony2 project, I am getting this error message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput::isVerbose() in /var/staging_www/www.sciforum.net/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/CacheClearCommand.php on line 87
```

Any idea? Thank you.

EDIT:

When trying to update vendors, I am getting this error message:

```
Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput::isVerbose() in /var/staging_www/www.sciforum.net/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/CacheClearCommand.php on line 99
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception



[RuntimeException]
An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.
```

Comment: FYI you can delete the cache manually. `sudo rm -rf app/cache`

Comment: I know that, but the problem himself is not fixed.

Comment: Have you updated via composer?

Comment: Yes, and at the end I am getting an error message, see my updated uestion.

Comment: Can you try removing `vendor` directory, running `composer clear-cache` and then `composer update`? Composer tries to pull stuff from cache if possible and this is sometimes an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your versions in composer.json (and double-check versions for Symfony-based libraries in composer.lock). `isVerbose` only became available in ConsoleOutput with version 2.4.

You may have some mixed versions of the Symfony libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can fixit if you delete the directories first:

```
sudo rm -rf app/logs
sudo rm -rf app/cache
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem. Disabling PHP `opcache` for CLI helped me.

Disable it in `php.ini`:

`opcache.enable_cli=0`

Save the file and try clearing the cache again.